# File download process does not start client side (even with Content-Disposition: attachment ; filename=<filename>)

Tags: javascript, jquery, webserver

The following code sends a GET request, for which the response is supposed to start a file download process on the client (Chrome).

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  traditional: true,
  async : false,
  url  : "/query", 
  data : parms,
  success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    $("#msg").text(data);
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('error');
  }
});
```

The response header has the required headers to initiate a file downoload (`Content-Disposition: attachment ; filename=2013_04_04.08_00_00-09_00_00.VOD.60.tda`). However, this doesn't happen. I do see the response content in the 'msg' id control.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Don't use AJAX for this. Append a (hidden) `<iframe>` to the page, set its source to the URL you want, and let the headers take care of the download

Comment: can you be more specific please... i need js to pull some values which are parameters for the server to produce the answer based on them. how do i do it using iframe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append an `iframe`, set its `src`, and wait for the response naturally.

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.style.display = "none";
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.src = "Your URL" + "?" + "Your GET Params";
```